# In android v.6 there is an app called ' FotaProvider ' in settings - is this a security issue?

Tags: android, security, operating-system

FOTA - < firmware over the air > enables updates in the background, FotaProvider (308 kb) is installed on many low-price Chinese android systems including mine and has been shown to be abused by certain Chinese companies - it has been used to obtain user info and send it back to China !!. My question - is this app safe ? I paid 80 euros for my phone an M20Pro android v.6 from Globalstar although it is marketed as a no-name - even no name on the battery.  I think this app cannot be uninstalled so easily. This could be a big security issue - so can anyone answer please? I've asked about this on several websites but without response.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. This is not a programming question.

Comment: @CommonsWare why is this not a programming question ?